# mongodb_hadoop streaming with python: -inputURI not recognized

Tags: python, mongodb, hadoop

I'm trying to create a MapReduce application in python using the mongodb_hadoop connecter. 
I have a cluster with hadoop 2.2.0 installed.
I've installed the mongodb_hadoop connector v1.3.0.
I've installed mongodb and created a test database called hadoop_db with a collection called "integers" containing integer values.

My goal is to try to count the occurences of each integer. I based my work on this [presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/mongodb/mongo-db-hadoop-and-humongous-mongotokyo-2012)

But when I try to execute the job, here is what I get:

```
bin/hadoop jar share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-2.2.0.jar \
-mapper pyhadoop/pymongotest/mapper.py \    
-reducer pyhadoop/pymongotest/reducer.py \
-inputURI mongodb://hadoopnode1/hadoop_db.integers \
-outputURI mongodb://hadoopnode1/hadoop_db.reducted_int

ERROR streaming.StreamJob: Unrecognized option: -inputURI
```

What is the correct option for this particular version of the connector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I finally found the correct command. I put it here so it may help anyone facing the same issue in the future:

```
bin/hadoop jar $HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-2.2.0.jar \
-libjars $HADOOP_HOME/lib/mongo-hadoop-streaming-1.3.0.jar \
-input /tmp/in \
-output /tmp/out \
-inputformat com.mongodb.hadoop.mapred.MongoInputFormat \
-outputformat com.mongodb.hadoop.mapred.MongoOutputFormat \
-io mongodb \
-jobconf mongo.input.uri=mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/hadoop_db.integers \
-jobconf mongo.output.uri=mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/hadoop_db.reducted_int \
-jobconf stream.io.identifier.resolver.class=com.mongodb.hadoop.streaming.io.MongoIdentifierResolver \
-mapper mapper.py \
-reducer reducer.py \ 
-file $HADOOP_HOME/pyhadoop/pymongotest/mapper.py \
-file $HADOOP_HOME/pyhadoop/pymongotest/reducer.py
```